# How is data lineage tracked in aws athena and glue?

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, data-lineage

Atlas is product of choice for Hadoop data lineage question. Is there any clear product for data lineage tracking on aws Athena or Glue.

Answer (score 0):

**No, there isn't.**

Athena is managed Presto.
Glue is a mix of a managed Hive Metastore and a Serverless Spark Cluster.

You can use Atlas on Elastic Map Reduce (EMR), there is a blog post about that:

[Metadata classification, lineage, and discovery using Apache Atlas on Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/metadata-classification-lineage-and-discovery-using-apache-atlas-on-amazon-emr/)